# Co-ordinates/ data marker in 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How to **place the data marker** or **see the co-ordinates in below 3D plot** and how to list all data points in this plot?

```
Table[DiscretePlot3D[PDF[MultinomialDistribution[n, {0.5, 0.5}], {x, y}], 
                     {y, 0, n}, {x,0, n}, PlotLabel -> Row[{"n = ", n}], 
                     ExtentSize -> 0.5], 
      {n, {5}}]
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "place the data marker"? Those prisms you see ARE the data markers ...

Comment: I mean numerical values/co-ordinates of a plotted data.

Comment: Add `Axes -> True` to the plot

Comment: do I need to do further more clicks somewhere to finally see the numerical value?

Comment: I'm not sure it is very  clear what you are asking, do you mean you want to use the mouse to click on the image to read off the coordinates where the mouse is ? Or do you mean something different, could you show us an image of what you require ?

Comment: I just need the co-ordinates (3D) in the plot. I need it because from the graph one get an illusion that there is one high peak in the graph, which is not true. The two tall blocks are equal in length in actual. Changing the orientation is not what I need.

Comment: Or forget  the plot, Listing all the numerical values would help me too.

Comment: If you just want the numerical values, will this work? 
With[{n = 5}, Table[PDF[MultinomialDistribution[n, {0.5, 0.5}], {x, y}],
 {y, 0,  n}, {x, 0, n}]] // TableForm

Comment: @BenP1192 That's helpful. But is it possible to include the domain (i-e x and y values) to be included in the table as well, so that makes easy to correspond which value belongs to which (x,y).

Comment: You can use Prepend to add column headers to the table, and MapThread with Prepend to add row headers. Someone else may be able to help you get it looking nice(I'm not the best at formatting).  But I used Grid, with a frame option to indicate that the first column/row are headers and not data
With[{n = 5}, 
 t = Table[
   PDF[MultinomialDistribution[n, {0.5, 0.5}], {x, y}], {y, 0, n}, {x,
     0, n}]; t = Prepend[t, Table[x, {x, 0, n}]]; 
 t = MapThread[Prepend, {t, Join[{"Y\\X"}, Table[y, {y, 0, n}]]}]; 
 Grid[t, Frame -> {1 -> True, 1 -> True}]]

Comment: @BenP1192 thanks for your help ! It surely help me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
With[{n = 5},
 Module[{
   prob = Union[
     Table[
      PDF[MultinomialDistribution[n, {.5, .5}], {k, n - k}],
      {k, -1, n}]],
   max},
  max = Max[prob];
  Row[{
    DiscretePlot3D[
     PDF[MultinomialDistribution[n, {.5, .5}], {x, y}],
     {y, 0, n}, {x, 0, n},
     AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@
        {"y", "x", 
         Rotate["Probability\n", Pi/2]}),
     PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["n = ``", n], 16, Bold],
     ExtentSize -> 0.5,
     ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#3] &),
     ImageSize -> 360],
    SwatchLegend[
     Opacity[.5, #] & /@
      (ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ (prob/max)),
     prob]}]]]
```

[image]